# Is the name Madori Japanese?

Tags: meaning, names

Yes, I do mean Madori and not Midori. I was told by my mother that it means 'angel of the sky.' I haven't found anything on this, however. In my research, I only found that it could be a variation of Midori and would therefore have the same meaning, but even that was only a guess.

Does anyone have any idea what my name could mean or was it just made up? I have come across many people with Madori as a last name, but never a first. Any help would be appreciated,thank you!

Comment: Absolutely. http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8A%20%23names

Answer (score 4):

I've never heard of the name *Madori*, but according to some Japanese baby names websites (e.g. [1](https://namejiten.com/%E5%A5%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%90/%E3%81%BE/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8A), [2](http://www.baby-name.jp/name134/134456.php)) it can be a Japanese female given name. A(n incomplete) list of various *kanji* representations is given in the [ENAMDICT database](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8A%20%23names) (via jisho.org).

In any case, given the rōmaji transcription of a Japanese name (e.g. "Madori") it's usually impossible to say whether a "meaning" is correct. This is because names can be written with many different *kanji* (Chinese characters) and these determine the "meaning".

(Sometimes parts of the name are standard, which makes it possible to [make a reasonable guess](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44536/1628) on its meaning. For example, *-ko* in *Akiko*, *Mariko*, *Yōko*, etc. should be 子 "child".)

Some names also use *kanji*, which are likely used for sound rather than meaning:

> 麻都梨

This is likely a phonetic *kanji* representation of *Madori*, the individual characters meaning "hemp", "metropolis" and "Japanese pear".

Others, like 万鳥 "a thousand birds" (actually 10,000), are probably intended to carry more meaning.

I don't know which characters were used to derive the meaning "angel of the sky"; I can't even make a far-fetched guess. In any case, without the *kanji* representation, it's not possible to say anything definitive about the "meaning" of a name.

Comment: By the way it may be worth mentioning that まどり is rare as a person name. It never sounds that weird, but I'm not aware of any person (either in reality and in fiction) whose name is まどり.

Comment: This seems to be a good example of just how rare some of the entries of ENAMDICT are.

Comment: Actually, I guess now we all know one person (in virtual life) called Madori.

Comment: Indeed. I have too come across many "unorthodox" names, for example, Sarina, Takato ( but its Kanji means "a flying boy" ), Tumugi ( Wht does that mean??? ) Today's trend is a bit chaotic.