# How can I tell if a Japanese person's given name is male or female?

Tags: meaning, kanji, pronunciation, names

I am hoping that there may be some particular kanji and/or sounds used in determining if a persons given name is male or female.

Comment: For a particular name, https://namegen.jp/yomikata can give you statistics on whether the name is more probably male or female.

Comment: very helpful information.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are a number of common suffixes you can use to try to guess. Here is an incomplete list of common suffixes which are a pretty safe bet:

#### Female

- *ko* 子
- *mi* 美
- *ka* 花・華
- *e* 江・恵
- *na* 奈・菜
- *no* 乃
- *ri* 里

#### Male

- *rō* 郎
- *ta* 太
- *suke* 介・助・祐
- *o* 男・夫・雄・生
- *ya* 哉・也
- *kichi* 吉
- *hiko* 彦
- *nobu* 信

Also, "girly" *kanji*—like 愛 "love", 幸 "happiness", 華 "flower", 美 "beauty" etc.—or *hiragana* will usually indicate a girl's name.

Similarly, "boyish" *kanji*—like 正 "righteous", 健 "health/strength", 勝 "win", 信 "honesty", etc., will usually indicate a boy's name.

Comment: It should be added that girls names among the elderly today, born before the war, often is written with katakana, whereas men of that age usually used kanji. The reason for this is that katakana was the default kana in that time, whereas now hiragana has the default role and katakana special uses.

Comment: @bjorn Right, there are many more hints I haven't mentioned. However, if you see an all-*katakana* name, "probably a woman born before the war" is maybe not a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Is it okay to guess that many fiction names will trascend these patterns? For instance, I remember character named 忍(shinobu) which was a girl

Comment: @Earthliŋ also, do you know if when picking a name, do parents take account of the meaning of the kanji in chinese, or japanese only?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Of course fiction can break all rules — [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45320/1628) is a good example of how strange or arbitrary names in fiction are no real obstruction to building a narrative.

Comment: 小野妹子、蘇我馬子、中臣鎌子、 阿部鳥子, etc. were all **male**.

Comment: @l'électeur I really think it's ridiculous to downvote this answer, because you found exceptions to **a rule of thumb** ("a pretty safe bet") from people living in the 8th century or earlier... (Of course everyone's free to vote however they like.)

Comment: @FelipeOliveira 'Shinobu' 忍 does not have the -nobu *ending* 信.

Comment: @AeonAkechi do you mean that it's not really the sound/pronnunciation that dictates weather the name is male or female, but rather the kanji used? I'm not very familiar with names and naming in general in japanese tbh

Comment: @FelipeOliveira I mean, these suffixes like -nobu and -ko are attached to something else. 'Shinobu' is just the full word.

Answer (score 5):

There are many examples where it can be absolutely impossible.

Here are two examples:

雅 - Masa (male name) or Miyabi (female name)

幸 - Kou (male name) or Miyuki (female name)

Comment: Makoto is an androgynous name not just in writing but in speech.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the name indicating itself whether it's male or female, I find the easiest way to work it out is doing a Google Image search for that name.

However, I'd advise caution about doing this at work. I have a recollection that sometimes the top results for female names involve women who aren't naked, but aren't wearing much more than their underwear. For an example, try doing "Hitomi" in romaji, even with safe search on.

Some online dictionaries indicate whether a name is male or female, such as jisho.org, though you have to tell it you're specifically after names.

Answer (score 1):

There is a webservice for determine the gender of a name.

https://genderize.io/

Comment: It's a neat idea. The counts for Japanese names even romaji seem extremely low. Also, it doesn't mark some names that are clearly possible for either gender (try https://api.genderize.io/?name=makoto  , https://api.genderize.io/?name=%E8%AA%A0　)