# 孫悟飯 - Songohan, why non-Japanese say it comes from "gohan = meal/cooked rice"?

Tags: names, manga, anime, puns

As a French I've always heard that Songohan's name comes from *gohan* meaning *meal*/*cooked rice*. The English Wiki says the same and even mentions ご飯.

But I don't understand why, since the names in the family are like this:

- 孫悟空 *Songokū*
- 孫悟飯 *Songohan*
- 孫悟天 *Songoten*

So it seems only the last kanji changes between the characters, and since 飯 alone already means *meal*/*cooked rice*, and 悟飯 alone doesn't mean anything, why do we focus on *gohan* and not only *han* to explain the name of the character?

---

EDIT: after reading your answers, I realized my mistake was to read 飯 alone as *han*. That's why I didn't understand people saying "the name means *meal* because of *go + han*" since to me *han* alone already meant *meal*.

I'm sure noone understands what I mean but thank you, it's clear now.

Comment: Pun. It's a pun.

Answer (score 19):

It's a pun. In fact, many, many of Dragonball's characters are puns on food (or food-related) items:

- サイヤ人 *Saiyajin* from [ヤサイ]{野菜}人 "vegetable people"
- ベジータ *Vegeta* from ベジタブル "vegetable"
- ウーロン *Oolong* from 烏龍 (type of tea)
- ピラフ *Pilaf*
- ランチ *Lunch*
- ヤムチャ *Yamcha* from 飲茶【やむちゃ】 (snacks & tea)
- カリン塔【とう】 *Korin Tower* from 花林糖【かりんとう】 (type of sweets)
- バーダック *Burdock* from 牛蒡【ごぼう】 "burdock root"
- カカロット *Kakarrot* from 人参【キャロット】 "carrot"
- ギニュー *Ginyū* from 牛乳【ぎゅうにゅう】 "milk"
- バータ *Butta* from バター "butter"
- リクーム *Reacoom* from クリーム "cream"
- ジース *Jheese* from チーズ "cheese"
- フリーザ *Freezer* from "freezer" (like "fridge")
- etc.

<sub>For a full list see [Dragonball Wiki's Origins of character names](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Origins_of_character_names), which I found via [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/46145) on Anime.SE</sub>

So, 孫悟飯 doesn't literally mean "(cooked) rice", but it certainly alludes to it, like the names of so many other Dragonball characters.

By the way, you need *gohan* (here 悟飯) to make the pun work. 飯 by itself is read *meshi* and 飯【はん】 is not a word.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't really answer my question about *gohan* (which isn't very clear, I admit).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps I added a line to my answer. See if this answers your question about *gohan*.

Comment: Oh my, I was missing the point that 飯 alone cannot be read *han* to mean *meal/cooked rice*. So that's why the pun is on *gohan* and not *han*.